# Java getting resource relative path

Tags: java, path, resources, relative-path

I'm trying to load a .wav file into the memory, but It keep telling me that the file doesn't exists.

```
String filename;

public MyClass(String _filename){
 filename = _filename;
}

public void run(){
   InputStream in = View.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/"+filename);

   File inputFile = new File(in.toString());
   if(!inputFile.exists()){
      System.err.println("Wave file not found: " + in.toString());
      return;
   }
}
```

Console:

> Wave file not found: java.io.FileInputStream@dd5b524
>
> Wave file notfound: java.io.FileInputStream@570add96

The file is in the package folder. It's in

> myPackage/sounds/write.wav

**EDIT:**

Actually I want to load the sound:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sounds/"+filename);

AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
try { 
     audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) { 
         e1.printStackTrace();
         return;
} catch (IOException e1) { 
         e1.printStackTrace();
         return;
}
```

But the console is still with error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-6" Exception in thread "Thread-7"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
>     at com.chrissman.threads.AePlayWave.run(AePlayWave.java:47)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
>     at com.chrissman.threads.AePlayWave.run(AePlayWave.java:47)

Comment: Move your sounds directory in the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

`in.toString()` does not return the path used to open the stream, it returns the class name followed by the hash: `java.io.FileInputStream@dd5b524`.

The error is because you do not have a file named `java.io.FileInputStream@dd5b524` in your current directory.

**Since you got an object instead of `null` as `in` it found your file**. You can not use a `File` object to get this file, but you have access to it via the `in` object. Read the contents from the stream and use it.

Comment: and where I should call in.avaible()? Is this a solution for my problem?

Comment: There is almost never a reason to call `available()`.

Comment: I edited it. My point is, your file opened ok. But there is no `File` object needed.

Comment: Change the second example to use the same path as the first one (`"/sounds/"+filename`) and it should open ok.

Answer (score 0):

Resources can be looked up both with a absolute and relative path. What you currently have is an absolute path starting with `/`. So change it into `/myPackage/sounds/write.wav`. In general I prefer absolute paths as it can be quite hard to determine which package is the "current" with relative paths.

Comment: and how to use absolute path?

Comment: If the first character is '/' then you refer to it as an absolute path.

Comment: Look in the .jar file then and verify that the file actually got packaged.

Comment: Yes, the file is in the package.

the package is called "com.chrissman", within this package I have a folder called "sounds", within this folder I have the .wav file "write.wav";